# Check string whether is UTF-8 or UCS-2

Tags: php, utf-8, ucs2

If I have a list of data:

`$a = "hello";`

`$b=  "4f60";`

`$c = "hi";`

`$d = "00480065006C006C006F";`

$b and $d are UCS-2 string.
I wish to display all these data in a table,so how can I know whether which data is UCS-2 so that I can convert it before being displayed ? Is it possible ? I tried mb_detect_encoding and preg_match for unicode found at php.net , but even it is an unknown symbol it still considered as unicode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the strings you show are hexadecimal representations, not the actual UCS-2 or UTF-8 encodings.

That said, there are some pretty huge differences between [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description) and [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) that would allow you to write code that correctly detects the encoding with a really high success rate. But before doing that, show us how you are using `mb_detect_encoding` and it's not working. No sense in reinventing a worse wheel than already exists.

**Update:** Your input strings are not actually the encoded byte values; they are *hex representations* of the values. To undo this, you can use

```
$proper_string = pack('H*', $hex_encoded_string);
```

After this, `mb_detect_encoding` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your information , I'm lack of knowledge in encoding...Honestly , I been searching and trying many methods for hours , so I not really remember how I used mb_detect_encoding,but should be something like this: `mb_detect_encoding("4f60","UTF-8",true)`, or simply `mb_detect_encoding("4f60")`,and many more though..

Comment: Really thanks for your help . Hopefully you won't mind for one more question..is it possible to return false if failed in pack() ? If I `pack('H*',"hi")` , it will return warning (illegal hex digit) , so that I know this message do not need to be converted, so I simply tried a way `function packing($string) { if(pack('H*',$string)) { return true; }  }` , but of course it won't works....

Comment: @IreneLing: No, you can't use that unconditionally. You have to know what kind of string you are working with beforehand.

Comment: I see , guess I have to think of other method again.. Thank you very much for your help.